# How do I make the IL Viewer work with Unity projects in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cil, rider

In Rider, when I open the IL Viewer I get a message "Build your project to view IL". However, Unity is in charge of the entire build process, so build through Rider is not possible. Is there a way making the IL Viewer work with Unity projects ?

Perhaps by telling Rider to read the built project from `Library/ScriptAssemblies` ?

I've looked around in the IDE settings but could not find anything related to this.